# How to reproduce @using(Html.BeginForm()){ ... } in Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know that if I write: `@using(Html.BeginForm(...){ ... }`, it will generate some form element: `<form action=...>...</form>`

I'd like to mimic similar behavior with my own elements, e.g. I will write:

`@using(Html.MyCustomContainer()){ <some cshtml content here> }`

and it should start some custom div element and close it when `}` is reached. How does this mechanism work on the inside? I've tried making my method return a class which is `IDisposable` and overriddent `Dispose` of it (as I'd expect `Dispose` to be called at the end when `}` is reached, and rendered the closing tag there, but it didn't work.

How can I create my own `@using(Html.MyCustomContainer()` method that works the same way as `Html.BeginForm()` does?

Comment: pretty sure BeginForm's Dispose method just does .WriteLine("</form>");

Comment: @Steve yeah I've tried that too but didn't work. are you 100% certain about this behavior? if yes, I'll look for something else in my code.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu, Its taken from a working project. I assure you it works :)